# haskell second largest element from list

Tags: list, haskell, max, fold

I have this function that returns the second largest value from a given list:

```
import Data.List

secondL :: Ord a => [a] -> a
secondL xs = 
  let  x = head xs 
  in  let  find (a, b) x = (min b (max a x), max b x) 
     in  fst  (foldl find (x, x) xs)
```

This function should be working correctly, but for better purity I would like to exclude the function `find`'s definition which is inside, and rework this function so that there is no other function declaration inside.

I was thinking about including `(min b (max a x), max b x)` into `foldl` argument, but this doesn't seem to be working well.

Comment: If there are *two* maximums (so the same value), do you return that value, or a value that is *strictly*& below* the maximum.

Comment: What should each of these return? `secondL []`, `secondL [0]`, `secondL [0,0]`, `secondL [0,1,1]`

Answer (score 3):

```
listToMaybe . take 1 . drop 1 . sortBy (flip compare)
  :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
```

will do this for you. It is even linear, because Haskell is lazy, and Haskell's `sort` is mergesort.

If you meant second largest, not second among the largest, you can just stick a `nub` in there to get it:

```
listToMaybe . take 1 . drop 1 . nub . sortBy (flip compare)
  :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
```

It'll still be linear.

Trying it out:

```
> listToMaybe . take 1 . drop 1 . nub . sortBy (flip compare) $ [1,3,2,3,1]
Just 2

> listToMaybe . take 1 . drop 1 . nub . sortBy (flip compare) $ [3,3,3]
Nothing
```

(use https://hoogle.haskell.org/ to search for functions)

---

If you want to code it with left fold specifically, then

```
foo :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
foo xs 
   | [_,y] <- foldl' g [] xs  =  Just y
   | otherwise  =  Nothing
  where
  g ys x  =  take 2 . nub . reverse . sort $ x:ys
```

Writing `g` out by hand with all the comparisons and the checks needed (or itself as a fold) is left as an exercise.